# C++ how to check if the difference of two millisecond values is positive?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I need to introduce minimum 2 seconds delay. For that I have done this:

```
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
typedef std::chrono::milliseconds Milliseconds;
Clock::time_point t0 = Clock::now();

// DO A LOTS OF THINGS HERE.....

Clock::time_point t1 = Clock::now();
Milliseconds delayTime = Milliseconds(2000) - 
     std::chrono::duration_cast<Milliseconds>(t1 - t0); 

// Check if time left from initial 2 seconds wait the difference
if (delayTime > Milliseconds(0))
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(delayTime);
}
```

Did I check correctly if still time left?

Comment: If there is more time left than 2 seconds after doing LOTS OF THINGS.

Comment: For a minimum you should check >=, otherwise 2 seconds exactly won't work. Otherwise, yes, this looks correct.

Comment: @ChristopherWirt in this case, `sleep_for(0)` is not necessary. I can't see any reason to use `>=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you *really* need to ensure that you don't call sleep at all if the 2 seconds has already elapsed, it seems like it would be a lot easier to compute when the sleep should end, then call `sleep_until`, passing that time.

```
auto t1 = Clock::now() + 2s; // beware: requires C++14

// do lots of things here

std::this_thread::sleep_until(t1);
```

If 2 seconds has already elapsed, the `sleep_until` (at least potentially) returns immediately. If it hasn't elapsed yet, the thread sleeps until the specified time.

Comment: What notation is `2s`? How I should understand it?

Comment: It is a [user-defined litteral](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). Especially [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s).

Answer (score 4):

Something like that should do the trick, even though your attempt seems correct in the first place :

```
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
typedef std::chrono::milliseconds Milliseconds;
Clock::time_point t0 = Clock::now();

// DO A LOTS OF THINGS HERE.....

Clock::time_point t1 = Clock::now();
auto elapsed_time = std::chrono::duration_cast<Milliseconds>(t1 - t0);
auto duration = Milliseconds(2000);

// Check if time left from initial 2 seconds wait the difference
if (elapsed_time < duration)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration - elapsed_time);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, it avoids checking if the value is positive, but I would like to know if my check is correct, or it will have some problems? It works on Windows with MVS2012, but I am not sure I have done the right thing.

Comment: [`std::thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) documentation says nothing about a potential negative duration, and I can't find any information with a quick Google search, so I guess there is nothing wrong with your initial attempt. Might be implementation dependant.